# Module parse failed: Unexpected token on HTMLSelectElement Typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack

How to fix this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmPnI.png)? Why do not works HTMLSelectElement? I build with webpack. Another modules works. If I remove HTMLSelectElement, cant build, because

> Error TS2339  (TS) Property 'options' does not exist on type
> 'HTMLElement'.

**index.cshtml**

```
<select class="form-control me-2" name="select">
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="submit">Search</button>
```

**index.ts**

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const select = document.getElementsByName("select")[0] as HTMLSelectElement;
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './Scripts/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: __dirname
            + "/wwwroot/js",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',
    optimization: {
        usedExports: true,
    }
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "node_modules"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "include": [
    "Scripts/*.ts"
  ]
}
```